# Umbraco 10 403 and other errors

Tags: .net-6.0, http-status-code-403, umbraco9

I are trying to deploy my first umbraco 10 website to plesk hosting service.

Have published the site using visual studio 17 and the site is up and running fine however when I go to the back office the page is blank. at best I get the menus across the top. But none of the tree or information in the main part of the screen.

I do get these errors up

```
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/backofficeassets/GetSupportedLocales
Contact your administrator for information.
×
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/updatecheck/GetCheck
Contact your administrator for information.
×
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
LocalizedText
Contact your administrator for information.
×
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/tour/GetTours
Contact your administrator for information.
×
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/contenttype/AllowsCultureVariation
Contact your administrator for information.
×
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/section/GetSections
Contact your administrator for information.
×
Authorization error: Unauthorized access to URL:
/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/section/GetSections
Contact your administrator for information.
```

If I look at the console I have these errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get tours","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/language/GetAllLanguages:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get languages","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/dashboard/GetDashboard?section=content:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get dashboard content","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/dashboard/GetDashboard?section=media:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get dashboard media","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/dashboard/GetDashboard?section=content:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get dashboard content","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/views/common/drawers/help/help.html?umb__rnd=55cf41cb7a843f406e64be738e39702729f99e46:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/authentication/GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Server call failed for checking remaining seconds","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/dashboard/GetDashboard?section=media:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get dashboard media","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
(anonymous) @ umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147
umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/dashboard/GetDashboard?section=content:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
umbraco-backoffice-js.js.vbff92525987e3f7cfb9c113a93c5c023af38d7bc:147 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get dashboard content","data":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":403}
```

If I then refresh the page I get a 403 error on both the front end and the backend.

If check the access for all files and folders and made sure they have full read right access.

The website works fine locally in debug mode from VS.

Comment: did you find out what caused this? we seem to have the same errors. random 403s when clicking stuff inside backoffice

Comment: Yea I did it was due to the firewall my service provider has. In the settings I could set of settings "switch of security settings" where there is a whole list and I have one called "multi-platform".  turn this one off and it runs fine. What it does I dont know but you could confirm its a firewall issue by disabling your wirewall.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this incase someone else has this issue, since the fix on our end was different (ref comment)

We had set up a new server, but certain IIS settings were overlooked. Within the "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" section, there exists a submenu containing default values for maximum concurrent requests (or something similar), which were set to 5.

So, when Umbraco was generating multiple requests as it typically does when pages are clicked, some of these requests were stopped, leading to a 403 error. When we deactivating this feature, the issue was resolved, and now everything is functioning as it should.